# how to get cropped image name and path after cropping

Tags: android

I want to get image name and path of the cropped image. After that I want to upload the cropped image to server. I have tried using the below code. But it showing errors.

```
take.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    // call android default camera
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.toString());
                    // ******** code for crop image
                    intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
                    intent.putExtra("aspectX", 0);
                    intent.putExtra("aspectY", 0);
                    intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
                    intent.putExtra("outputY", 150);

                    try {
                        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);

                    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    // Do nothing for now
                    }
                }
            });

            choose.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    // call android default gallery
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    // ******** code for crop image
                    intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
                    intent.putExtra("aspectX", 0);
                    intent.putExtra("aspectY", 0);
                    intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
                    intent.putExtra("outputY", 150);

                    try {
                        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
                        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_GALLERY);

                    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                        // Do nothing for now
                    }
                }
            });


public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_CAMERA) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data");
            iv1.setImageBitmap(photo);

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            // Get the cursor
            Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            // Move to first row
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            imgPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            // Get the Image's file name
            String fileNameSegments[] = imgPath.split("/");
            fileName = fileNameSegments[fileNameSegments.length - 1];
            // Put file name in Async Http Post Param which will used in Php web app
            params.put("filename", fileName);
            encodeImagetoString();
        }
    }

    if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_GALLERY) {
        Bundle extras2 = data.getExtras();
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        if (extras2 != null) {
            Bitmap photo = extras2.getParcelable("data");
            iv1.setImageBitmap(photo);


            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            // Get the cursor
            Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            // Move to first row
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            imgPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            // Get the Image's file name
            String fileNameSegments[] = imgPath.split("/");
            fileName = fileNameSegments[fileNameSegments.length - 1];
            // Put file name in Async Http Post Param which will used in Php web app
            params.put("filename", fileName);
            encodeImagetoString();
        }
    }
}
```

And the error is,

```
08-27 00:20:32.310: E/AndroidRuntime(3816): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-27 00:20:32.310: E/AndroidRuntime(3816): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65538, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {com.example/com.example.UpdateProfile}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-27 00:20:32.310: E/AndroidRuntime(3816):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3367)
08-27 00:20:32.310: E/AndroidRuntime(3816):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3410)
08-27 00:20:32.310: E/AndroidRuntime(3816):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-27 00:20:32.310: E/AndroidRuntime(3816):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1304)
08-27 00:20:32.310: E/AndroidRuntime(3816):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-27 00:20:32.310: E/AndroidRuntime(3816):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-27 00:20:32.310: E/AndroidRuntime(3816):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
08-27 00:20:32.310: E/AndroidRuntime(3816):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-27 00:20:32.310: E/AndroidRuntime(3816):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-27 00:20:32.310: E/AndroidRuntime(3816):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
08-27 00:20:32.310: E/AndroidRuntime(3816):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-27 00:20:32.310: E/AndroidRuntime(3816):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-27 00:20:32.310: E/AndroidRuntime(3816): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-27 00:20:32.310: E/AndroidRuntime(3816):     at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1144)
08-27 00:20:32.310: E/AndroidRuntime(3816):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:398)
08-27 00:20:32.310: E/AndroidRuntime(3816):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:357)
08-27 00:20:32.310: E/AndroidRuntime(3816):     at com.example.UpdateProfileHome.onActivityResult(UpdateProfileHome.java:459)
08-27 00:20:32.310: E/AndroidRuntime(3816):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:165)
08-27 00:20:32.310: E/AndroidRuntime(3816):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5322)
08-27 00:20:32.310: E/AndroidRuntime(3816):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3363)
```

The error is pointing at line 459 and the code at line 459 is,

```
Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
```

Is there any way to solve this issue. I have tried a lot to solve this error. But no Success.

Is it possible to get cropped image name and path.

Comment: basically u r trying to get thumbnial of image isnt it

Comment: @N5. :-  I want to get the image after cropped.

Comment: Try to replace `getActivity()` with `this` or with `getApplicationContext()`

Comment: @alfasin :- It is not possible because my class extends Fragment.

Comment: try this getActivity().getApplicationContext()

Comment: @N5. :- i have tried this too. But same error.

Comment: I'm confused: how do you have a `onActivityResult()` inside a fragment ?